# Can I take this wall out?

Tags: walls, load-bearing, beam

Good evening,
I decided to start a kitchen reno in our new house and wanted to take out this wall. I assumed it was not load bearing as it runs parallel to the joists, but after taking drywall off I was surprised to see 3 back to back 2x4 beside the opening and 2 2x4 at the ceiling.

I would still assume this is not load bearing and instead a builder going over board(I've never seen this in previous renos) but thought I'd ask here to see if anyone has more experience.

Here is a picture:
[image]

I also assume that the wall in connects to is load bearing. I am hoping to put a beam and 2 posts across and making it a half wall, does anyone know the span I'm allowed between posts for something like this? Or what size beam? There is currently no beam in the wall, it is just a normal 2x4 wall from what i can see. The joists are 2x8 and 16 inches center to center. They span around 30 feet across the house. Maybe they were engineered and it isn't a load bearing wall?

Here is a picture of the roof framing, if it helps:

[image]

There is another one of those little walls on the other side of attic as Well, and the wall below is basically right in between the two.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you will need to keep the major load-bearing pole (with the sandwiched boards.  The single boards can probably be removed.  Might want to have someone do a walk-through with you for an up close and personal estimate of the effects of the changes.

Comment: You're going to want  to have an engineer/architect take a look.  They should be able to tell you if it's safe to remove the wall, as well as design a beam that can be used in the other wall.  While it may cost a few dollars to have a pro take a look, it's far cheaper than repairing a collapsed house.

Comment: Thanks, any rough idea on what this should cost before I start calling around?